# Exponentials, Logarithms & the Natural Log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone show me how to solve this problem?  I don't know what "\" in front of "ln" means either.

Solve the following equation for $y = f(x)$.

$$e^y = e^{2y}e^{\ln(2x)}$$

Comment: The "\" in front of the natural log ("ln") is not part of math, but rather just the way we format math text on this site.  So, it's really just a formatting thing, not a math thing

Comment: And now it has been removed rendering the question meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^y = e^{2y}e^{\ln(2x)}\Rightarrow e^{-y}=e^{\ln(2x)}\Rightarrow -y=\ln2x\Rightarrow y=\ln{\frac{1}{2x}}$$